# How to merge Resize and Scroll function - Jquery

Tags: jquery

Need to change the value of pixels variable for Scrolltop **OR** make working two functions together.

A fixed bar must appear and disappear after tot pixel scrolled, but if window width change, even the height change, so need to do a little adjustment...

I use this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($(window).innerWidth() < 501) {
        $('#fixed_bar').css({"top":"50px"});
        var pixels = "270";
    } else {
        $('#fixed_bar').css({"top":"0"});
        var pixels = "500";
    }

    $(window).resize(function(){
        if ($(window).innerWidth() < 501) {
            $('#fixed_bar').css({"top":"50px"});
            var pixels = "270";
        } else {
            $('#fixed_bar').css({"top":"0"});
            var pixels = "500";
        }
    });
    $(window).on("scroll load", function(){
        if ($(this).scrollTop() >= pixels ) { //<-- this var not change when window resize
            $("#fixed_bar").fadeIn(200);
        } else {
            $("#fixed_bar").fadeOut(200);
        }
    });
});
```

I'm newbie on jquery, but i'm not able to understand why this code is not work.

Hope in your help. Thanks.

Comment: Pretty sure `scroll load `event dos not exists...  `$(window).on("scroll load",` <--- incorrect.  Also make [mre] and be specific about what does not work...

Comment: @ikiK does not exist??? Incorrect??? Look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/50352343/4167976

Comment: Seems you are right... Last code on page... https://api.jquery.com/on/ I was thinking it needs to be separted by coma, but that is reserved for additional filtering of elements of binded initial el...

Comment: @ikiK i have updated the code, maybe now is understand better

Comment: Well did you troubleshot it? Did you `console.log.($(this).scrollTop())` -   `console.log.(pixels)` -    `console.log.("scrolling") `  inside that event to see if it fires, when it fires, and what are the values? You still haven't provided [mre], doubt anyone can help you without it.

Comment: Also I would remove that last event out of document ready, you have window on load inside document ready...

Comment: @ikiK https://jsfiddle.net/z8ctryep/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your declaration of variable outside of all events and set the value inside, and not re - declaring it all the time inside.

Now your resize event will update the value and on scroll will use it.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/u1962kdL/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var pixels = ""

    if ($(window).innerWidth() < 501) {
        $('#fixed_bar').css({"top":"50px"});
        pixels = "270";
    } else {
        $('#fixed_bar').css({"top":"0"});
        pixels = "500";
    }

    $(window).resize(function(){
        if ($(window).innerWidth() < 501) {
            $('#fixed_bar').css({"top":"50px"});
            pixels = "270";
        } else {
            $('#fixed_bar').css({"top":"0"});
            pixels = "500";
        }
        //console.log(pixels) 

    });
    
    $(window).on("scroll", function(){
        console.log(pixels) 
        if ($(this).scrollTop() >= pixels ) { //<-- this var not change when window resize
            $("#fixed_bar").fadeIn(200);
        } else {
            $("#fixed_bar").fadeOut(200);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your working fiddle, now is ok! Many many thanks again! :)